# Update Statement Fails

Tags: sql, msg

I have a table called `[dbo].[ProductComponentRelationship]` with 4 fields

```
[ProductComponentRelationshipID] PK, INt, Not Null
[ProductItemID] FK, Int Not Null
[ComponentItemID] FK, Int, Not Null
[SequenceNumber] int null
```

This table houses a bunch of values. I need to update 4000 records in the table above. Therefore i populated a seperate table with a productItemID, and the new ComponentitemID value. I tried to run the sql statement below and it failed:

```
update ProductComponentRelationship set ComponentItemID = 
(select compid from cst_pricefix where 
ProductComponentRelationship.ProductItemID = cst_pricefix.prditem and 
ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID = ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID )

Error Message: 
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ComponentItemID', table 'SDSDB.dbo.ProductComponentRelationship'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Comment: Seems straight forward.  You are setting that field to null and it fails because it cannot be set to null.  Does this statement return anything?  select compid from cst_pricefix where ProductComponentRelationship.ProductItemID = cst_pricefix.prditem and ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID = ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server, which it looks like from the `dbo`, you can update over a join like so:

```
update
    pcr
set
    ComponentItemID = f.compid
from
    ProductCompnentRelationship pcr
        inner join
    cst_pricefix f
        on pcr.ProductItemID = f.prditem
```

I'm not sure what `ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID = ProductComponentRelationship.ProductComponentRelationshipID` was about in your original query, so there may be something missing from mine.